# How to iterate through a DateTime List and send to a function as parameter

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

How do I iterate through a list which is returning a DateTime List and pass individual dates into a function which is expecting a DateTime parameter ?
Below is my LINQ query that returns List of Dates:

```
var lastModifiedDates = context.Reviews
                               .Where(s => s.IsActive == true)
                               .Where(s => s.ReviewStatusId == (int)ReviewStatuses.EmployeeSignature)
                               .Select(v => v.ModifiedDate)
                               .ToList();
```

Here is how I am trying to pass dates:

```
foreach (var lastModifiedDate in lastModifiedDates)
{
    AddBusinessDay(lastModifiedDate, 15);                 
}
```

Here is how `AddBusinessDay` function looks like:

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDay (DateTime date, int days)
```

On `AddBusinessDay(lastModifiedDate, 15);` I get the following error:

> Error 28  The best overloaded method match for 'EvaluationFormAccess.AddBusinessDay(System.DateTime, int)' has some invalid arguments

Review entity:

```
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ReviewGuid { get; set; }
    public int ReviewStatusId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int SupervisorId { get; set; }
    public int ReviewYearId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> EmployeeOnLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PlanInPlace { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeComments { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSignature { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EmployeeSignDate { get; set; }
    public string ManagerComments { get; set; }
    public string ManagerSignature { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ManagerSignDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the type of `v.ModifiedDate`?

Comment: You don't need the `.ToList()` at the end of that either. Just the `IEnumerable<DateTime>` is enough for you to `foreach` on.

Comment: @sstan v.ModifiedDate is type DateTime

Comment: Hard to believe.  Can you post your `Review` entity?

Comment: One of your assuptions is wrong.  I'm going to assume that v.ModifiedDate is not a DateTime.  Double check it please.  Either that, or you are calling AddBusinessDay with lastModifiedDates by accident in your real code.

Comment: yes @sstan posting it now. I checked it is DateTime

Comment: @HereToLearn_ That doesn't make sense, then. Are you *sure* it's not `DateTime?` - note the `?`. Just to triple check: before your call to the method, write `var t = lastModifiedDate().GetType()`, chuck a breakpoint on it and show us the result

Comment: Yeah.. from your edit it's definitely *not* a DateTime. Change your query to be : `.Where(v => v.ModifiedDate.HasValue).Select(v => v.ModifiedDate.Value);`

Comment: thank you sir@Rob this is exactly what was missing!!!

Comment: also a very nice check to make sure I am checking that ModifiedDate has value then only add it to list of ModifiedDates! post this as answer so i can accept it :) @Rob

Comment: @Ksv3n Go ahead and undelete the answer, mate - we both came to the same conclusion at the same time anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ModifiedDate` property is actually a `Nullable<DateTime>` (also can be written as `DateTime?`), which is actually *not at all* a `DateTime`.

You have two options:

Resolve the *possible* `DateTime` into an *actual* `DateTime` in your LINQ query:

```
var lastModifiedDates = context.Reviews
                        .Where(s => s.IsActive == true)
                        .Where(s => s.ReviewStatusId == (int)ReviewStatuses.EmployeeSignature)
                        .Where(v => v.ModifiedDate.HasValue)
                        .Select(v => v.ModifiedDate.Value)
                        .ToList();
```

Or do it in your loop:

```
foreach (var lastModifiedDate in lastModifiedDates)
{
    if (lastModifiedDate.HasValue)
        AddBusinessDay(lastModifiedDate.Value, 15);                 
}
```

Loop solution courtesy of [Ksv3n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3655779/ksv3n)